# Relational Database Design decomposition and closure?

Tags: closures, relational-database, relationship, functional-dependencies, decomposition

I have been trying to solve these two questions, but haven't had much luck.

Question 1: Show that the decomposition rule:
A → BC implies A → B and A → C,
is a sound rule, namely, that the functional dependencies A → B and A → C
are logically implied by the functional dependency A → BC.

Question 2: Let F be the following collection of functional dependencies
for relation schema R = (A, B, C, D, E):
D → A
BA → C
C → E
E → DB .
a) Compute the closure F + of F .
b) What are the candidate keys for R? List all of them.
c) List the dependencies in the canonical cover of the above set of
dependencies F (in other words, compute F c , as we have seen in class).

Any input will be helpful.